# How to call the function of this repository in another service?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I used Spring Boot Web, Spring Data JPA and PostgreSQL to create an application. The function `findByName(topping)` still works in the *topping* service, it still return a value. However, when I call this function in the *pizza* service, it returns `null` value.

I try to read the query that the two services generate to get topping from topping, and it returns the same query.

**pizza service**

```
@Override
public Pizza addTopping(@Valid String toppingName, Long pizzaId) {
    Pizza pizza = _pizzaRepository.getOne(pizzaId);
    
    Optional<PizzaTopping> topping = _toppingRepository.findByName(toppingName);
    if( topping.isEmpty())
    log.error("it's null bro!");
    
    return pizza.addTopping(topping.get());
}
```

**topping service**

```
@Override
public Optional<PizzaTopping> findToppingByName(String toppingName) {
    
    return _ToppingRepository.findByName(toppingName);
}
```

**topping repository**

```
public interface ToppingRepository extends JpaRepository<PizzaTopping, Long>{

    Optional<PizzaTopping> findByName(String toppingName);

    Optional<PizzaTopping> findPizzaToppingByName(String toppingName);

}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hard to say from that snippets. Put a break point at `addTopping()` and check if the `toppingName` exists at this time in DB. If the queries are equal the state of the DB it is probably not.

Comment: thanks! I found that when I demo API by using Swagger. I input "String" value, swagger didn't remove quotation marks before passed to function. So it return null value